# Stop autovacuum on old partition

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, autovacuum

We're having some issues when autovacuum triggers on one of our large tables (~100Gb).

Our ETL jobs only hit the last three partition of this table but, from my understanding, when autovacuum is triggered on a partition the whole table is vacuumed and this is causing the ETL job to wait until it's finished.

So far I've tried to set autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor to both a higher and lower value which yields approximately the same execution time for our job.

Since a rather important number of INSERT/UPDATE is performed on this table, I would like to put a low value for autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor on the three lasts partitions, but prevent the vacuuming of older partitions.

We are already using a vacuum script that runs every evening so I'm thinking about setting autovacuum_enabled to off on older partitionned and let the script handle the vacuum on these tables, but I'm not sure if it's the right way to treat this problem.

Another parameter I've stumbled upon is the vacuum_freeze_min_age and autovacuum_freeze_max_age, but I'm not sure I understand how to use them.

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56374/vacuum-freeze-vs-vacuum-full

Comment: Yes that is the post I found, but what I don't get is if this will provoke the transaction ID wraparound for the old partitions or if my vacuum script is enough to take care of that.

Comment: When an old partition is frozen and you don't insert, update or delete data from that partition, there is no need for vacuum on that partition anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but once the autovacuum is triggered by inserting on the newest partitions will it vacuum all the other child partitions once I set the vacuum_freeze_min_age ? And do I have tu run a VACUUM FREEZ after I set it ?

Comment: Auto_vacuum will not vacuum a frozen table (partition). You know when a table can be frozen, so run VACUUM FREEZE for this table (partition) when you know that this makes sense.

Comment: This description doesn't make any sense.  V12 will not auto-vacuum one partition based on changes to a different partition in the first place.  What are you seeing that makes you think any of this is actually happening?

Comment: Well the time at which the autovacuum is triggered corresponds to a gap of time in my ETL logs. Also, when the job is done my users encounter very slow response time from their queries and again corresponding to the exacte time the autovacuum triggers